# Speedometer is Chopy/Sticky

Tags: kia, speedometer

So this is an odd issue.

2005 Kia Spectra 109,000 miles (well maintained car)

My speedometer is choppy. The problem comes and goes right now.

When I am on the free way going 60 it might say 20 - 30mph it might say 0mph.

Before the problem starts the speedometer needle isn't smooth, it appears to be sticky or choppy.

I have gotten it to stop doing this two ways. First turning off the car seems to fix the problem temporarily and also sometimes coming to a complete stop fixes the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would bet the electronic speed sensor in the transmission is malfunctioning. It should look something like this:

[image: Pulled from RockAuto.com]

It suggests it is located at the top of the transmission, so should be fairly easy to get to. One plug, one bolt.

Comment: I just took it for a long drive and now everything is working again... When it starts malfunctioning again (im sure shortly) I will take it in and have them check this. Thank you +1 and check